# Настройка react tailwindcss datepicker (отображение месяцев)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Установил пакет react-tailwindcss-datepicker, все работает хорошо, но...
[image: как есть]

У меня настроен диапазон дат, которые пользователь может выбрать. В данном случае диапазон от 17 апреля до 10 мая. Но при открытии календаря в левом календаре открыт месяц май, в правом июнь. Июнь, в моем случае, весь перечеркнутый и не активен. Нужно сделать что бы при открытии в правом был текущий месяц, в левом предыдущий.
[image: как нужно]

Кто сталкивался помогите.

Компонент:

```html
<Datepicker 
  value={calendar} 
  onChange={handleValueChange} 
  showShortcuts={false}
  minDate={new Date(calendarMin)}
  maxDate={new Date(calendarMax)}
  displayFormat={"DD.MM.YY"}
  placeholder={"Выбрать дату"}
  separator={"-"}
/>
```